# Python pass value in class and def using .self

Tags: python, self, python-class

I want to pass some values to a def but am having issues with properly adding this.

In

```
class MyAddin():
    def __init__(self, imapinfopro, thisApplication): #also tried including _self.Table_Path in this.
        try:
            self._pro = imapinfopro
            self._thisApplication = thisApplication
            self._tab = None
            #self._table_path =(r'D:\junk\28355.tab')

            # Some standard variables to allow functions to be created for each action for easier use. r_ is for Ribbon actions
            r_item_name="Infrastructure_Data" #Name of button on main ribbon (no spaces allowed)
            r_button_name="Water" #same as operations in the ribbon_customization.py
            r_subroup_name="Not Abandoned" #same as "Table" and "CallBack" in the ribbon_customization.py
            r_subgroup_action="Open\nClose" #same as 'MB Handler\nNo Parameter'in the ribbon_customization.py

            tab = self._pro.Ribbon.Tabs.Add(r_item_name)
            self._tab = tab
            if tab:
                group = tab.Groups.Add(r_button_name, r_button_name)
                if group:
                    button = group.Controls.Add("ButtonOpenTable", r_subroup_name, ControlType.Button)
                    button.IsLarge = True
                    button.LargeIcon = CommonUtil.path_to_uri("pack://application:,,,/MapInfo.StyleResources;component/Images/Mapping/infoTool_32x32.png")
                    button.SmallIcon = CommonUtil.path_to_uri("pack://application:,,,/MapInfo.StyleResources;component/Images/Mapping/infoTool_16x16.png")
                    button.Command = AddinUtil.create_command(self.open_table_click)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to load: {}".format(e))

    def open_table_click(self, sender):
        #table_path=(r'D:\junk\28355.tab') #if left in this is used to open the table but I want to get this value from button.Command above.
        table = self._pro.Catalog.OpenTable(table_path)
        CommonUtil.do("map from {}".format(table.Alias))
        CommonUtil.do("browse * from {}".format(table.Alias))

    pass
```

I want to send the value for `table_path` in to `def open_table_click` from `button.Command = AddinUtil.create_command(self.open_table_click)`. If it wasn't a self call it would be ...`_command(self.open_table_click, tablepath)` and `def open_table_click(self, sender, table_path):`

Comment: What? There is no `table_path` in scope in that function. You provide an argument to `__init__` called `table_path`, but don't do anything with it... there's a bunch of commented out code... it would be *really* helpful if you provided a [mcve]. Most of this is totally irrelevant AFAIKT.  Perhaps in `__init__` you meant to assign `self.table_path = table_path`, then in `open_table_click` you could use `self.table_path`

Comment: Wait, do you mean pass `table_path` in `__init__` as the `sender` argument in `self.open_table_click`???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga currently if I uncommented `table_path=(r'D:\junk\28355.tab')` in the `open_table_click` it opens the table as expected. However I want to modify `button.Command` so that it sends the `table_path` as well and not have it in the def. This is so that I can use the `open_table_click` multiple times by passing different table_path values. I didn't include the whole code as this is python for Mapinfo and this was more about correctly including variables into the call.

Comment: Again, totally not clear what you mean. You have commented code all over the place, you **really must** provide a [mcve]. What do you mean "sends the `table_path` as well"??? Is that what you are expecting `open_table_click` to take *as an argument to it's `sender` parameter*? Why don't you just use an *instance variable*, i.e. `self.table_path`?

Comment: I have removed commented out code -the only ones remaining are either explanations of the variables or the code I tried to get this to work. All I want to be able to do is to send the value for table_path through the `button.Command` to `open_table_click` without having to have `table_path` in `open_table_click`

Comment: saying "send" here is ambiguous... I've already suggested one approach, to use an instance attribute `self.table_path`. Alternatively, you could add it as a paramter, and partially apply with the local variable `table_path` in `__init__` when you use `AddinUtil.create_command`, and again, without more details about how this library works, like, apparently, the callback is expecting a `sender` value, so if you add a parameter, you could pass `lambda sender: self.open_table_click(sender, table_path)`